# Using ExcelScript change font name depending on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, automation, office-scripts

Using Excel Script how can you change the font name of cells on a sheet if they have a specific Value?

I need to change cells to font name "Wingdings" if the cell has a "ü" as the value. The regular font name is "Calibri". The sheet range is $1:$1048576.

Was originally doing VBA which I need to transfer to ExcelScript.

VBA code:

```
Sub FormatText(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Range("$1:$1048576") Then
    If Target.Value = "ü" Then
    
        Target.Font.Name = "Wingdings"
    
    Else
    
        Target.Font.Name = "Calibri"
    
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You can adapt code to be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/resources/samples/excel-samples - for changing the font name you could also try using the recorder

Answer (score 0):

This task can be accomplished using Excel script code. For optimal efficiency, the code should check only the relevant range of cells (UsedRange) instead of iterating through every cell on the worksheet.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let sheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    let targetRange = sheet.getUsedRange();
    targetRange.getFormat().getFont().setName("Calibri");
    let values = targetRange.getValues();
    values.forEach((rowArray, rowIndex) => {
        rowArray.forEach((cellValue, colIndex) => {
            if (cellValue === "ü") {
                let cell = targetRange.getCell(rowIndex, colIndex);
                cell.getFormat().getFont().setName("Wingdings");
            }
        });
    });
}
```